# jQuery Slider next prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner with jQuery and I am trying work with a slider (as a way to learn how it works), which I downloaded from the web.

I was able to get the slider to show, but next and previous buttons do not work.

I will be glad if someone can help me with this.

I have not been able to figure out why the next and previous buttons are not working and how I should proceed to get them to work in jQuery.

Thanks.

Here is what I have in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsiveslides.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

 </head>
  <body>
  <header>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="blog"><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="rslides centered-btns centered btsn1" id="slider1">
    <li id="centered-btns1_s0" class="centered-btns1_on" style="display: block; float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
              <li id="centered-btns1_s1" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class=""><img src="img/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
              <li id="centered-btns1_s2" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class=""><img src="img/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
<a href="#" class="centered-btns_nav centered-btns1_nav prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="centered-btns_nav centered-btns1_nav next">Next</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </header>



<script>

$(function () {


  $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 800,
    namespace: "centered-btns"
  });

});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi, your html is invlaid - the next and prev should not be inserted in the html (especially not as a child of the ul) - the slider js should just create them for you.  If you remove the next and prev links and run the js.  Inspect your slider el;ement  and see if the buttons have been created.  You may just need to style them so they show up

Comment: They show up already. But if i click on next button it should be show up next image using jquery but this not happend. This i have now: http://prntscr.com/6bsy37